# Radio button values default to 0; how can I get "no action" for my POST message?

Tags: jquery, default, radiobuttonlist

I have a list of radio buttons that control the values posted back to the data base.  My problem is that, when I hit the SEND button, all of the unselected buttons have corresponding values set to 0, and those zeros overwrite the data base values I want to keep.

How can I modify the buttons so that their values default to "" (a null string)?

Comment: You can also update Database with "" when radio button has value of 0.

Comment: Cleaned up the problem statement.

Comment: Please post the markup and JS